# Webpack workbox plugin 3.0 - cache additional file (non webpack asset)

Tags: reactjs, webpack, service, worker, workbox

webpack-plugin to register service worker.

```
new CopyWebpackPlugin([
  { from: './src/manifest.json', to: '' },
  { from: './src/assets/homescreen', to: 'assets/homescreen/' }
]),
new WorkboxPlugin.GenerateSW({
  clientsClaim: true,
  skipWaiting: true
}),
```

My problem is that manifest.json isn't included in precache-manifets.js file. So the question is - how to cache additional files using workbox-webpack-plugin?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently `/^manifest.*\.js(?:on)?$/` is excluded in Workbox 3 by default.

It's fixed in Workbox v4.0.0-alpha.0. Get yourself the new version or try this trick:

```
    new InjectManifest({
        // some other options...
        exclude: [] // <-- Add this
      })
```

You may find this interesting:
https://github.com/GoogleChrome/workbox/pull/1679